# TortoiseSVN on USB key

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to use tortoiseSVN to manage some files that I need to transfer between my computers at work and at home.  Do I need to install TortoiseSVN on the USB key that I use to transfer the files?  Or will TortoiseSVN work without me having to do so?  If I need to install to the key, is that possible?  The .msi installer I downloaded doesnt' allow me to specify the directory for installation.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is a shell extension, you can't run it from a USB key. You can run other SVN clients using just the binary - most notably the command line client.

You should install TortoiseSVN on both machines, then simply update your files by first checking out and doing an `svn up` on each machine when you have commited changes.

Do you have access to the SVN server from both machines?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but you can put a repository or working folder on the key without installing TortoiseSVN to the key.

Where is your repository located? Is it accessble from both work and home?